# What does this INDEX value mean when comparing 2 files out of the git repo?

Tags: git

`git diff --no-index` can be used to compare 2 arbitrary files.

I tried as below:

```
$ git diff --no-index -- /d/a.txt /d/b.txt
diff --git a/D:/a.txt b/D:/b.txt
index 7c4a013..01f02e3 100644
--- a/D:/a.txt
+++ b/D:/b.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-aaa
\ No newline at end of file
+bbb
\ No newline at end of file
```

I think since I am comparing 2 files out of the git repo, there should be nothing to do with the INDEX. But what does the `index 7c4a013..01f02e3 100644` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` header in a diff does not refer to the Git index.  Instead, it contains the (usually abbreviated) object ID of the preimage file (the "old file" in a diff) followed by two dots and then the object ID of the postimage file (the "new file" in a diff).

This is generally just information about the diff and how it was produced, it is not (generally) used to validate that patch application was successful since the nature of patches is that you can apply a patch to an otherwise-changed file (for example, to effectively "cherry pick" the patch's contents on to a different branch).

There is one place that Git *does* validate the new object ID when applying a patch, however, which is when it applies a binary diff.  Unlike applying text patches which contain context to allow them to be retargeted and are indeed meant to be able to be applied to other files, binary patches make sense *only* when translating the *exact* preimage to the exact postimage.  As a result, Git will validate that the binary patch actually produces the *exact* output by comparing its hash to the hash presented in the `index` line.

Comment: I see similar `index` content in a patch file, I guess that's how git determines if a patch can be applied to a file or not.